# Possible To Set Control Properties Inside a Loop Without CodeBehind?

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Is it possible to set properties of an control inside a loop without using code behind? For example how can I set the `Text` property of the `LinkButton` inside the following loop at runtime, color being a POCO?

```
  <table>
  <%foreach (var color in GetColors()) {%>
    <tr>
      <td><asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%# ??color.MyProperty?? %>' /></td>           
    </tr>
    <%}%>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use repeater to bind the output from GetColors() to the control.

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but I guess what I'm trying to do is not possible @ runtime.